# Clever bulk update in Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, synchronization, bulk, angular-resource

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

Say you have a todo list and do the following changes:

- Mark as complete task 1
- Change the name of task 2
- Mark as complete task 2
- Change the name of task 1

At present, my system can achieve this by firing 4 http queries.
Is there a way Angular can sync the app with the server, say every 20 seconds, be able to notice when a change has been done on the same item, and group the changes into the same query.

The clever bulk update would then look like:

- Update task 1, SET complete=true, name= New name
- Update task 2, SET complete=true, name= New name

Has anyone ever tried this? Any idea which way I should search to find out more info about this kind of workflow?